# why are my environmental variables permanent?

Tags: tcsh

This problem has been bothering me for awhile. Occasionally I would set up an environmental variable in my .tcshrc file. As soon as I don't need it any more, I would remove it from my .tcshrc file; however, for some reason the variable became permanent in my shell. I thought that everything in the .tcshrc file were not meant to be permanent once the settings are commented or removed. This specifically happened to a new PATH that I wanted to add. Now that I don't need it any more, removing it from the .tcshrc file does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your .tcshrc is an executable script. You have to actually execute it for changes to it to have any effect. This typically occurs (automatically) when you start a new shell.

Another issue you may be running into is that environment varibles ar inherited by child processes. If your .tcshrc adds to variables rather than overwriting them (which isn't an uncommon thing to do with PATH) then this may cause the behavior you're seeing. Your current shell process has the extra entry in the PATH, and even though the child shell isn't *adding* it to the PATH (due to your recent .tcshrc change) it's already there.

Comment: In other words, if I add to an environmental variable like PATH, it would be permanent, but if I overwrite it, it would be temporary as long as the settings are in my .tcshrc? If so, how would I get around this issue? I thought that when the OS first loads, the parent shell that it creates would load everything from whatever is in /etc/tcshrc.tcshrc and the profile file. However, when I browse through these files, I only see the default PATH settings when my user account was created. Where did the parent shell get the extra settings that are not in my .tcshrc

Comment: Another variable that I created that became permanent was LS_COLORS. Not only that it became permanent, it was applied to all other shells(Bash, zsh, tcsh). I was trying to figure out how environmental variable works so I deleted that entry in my .tcshrc, but it was still there in all of my shells afterward.

Comment: @Hien Neither of the situations I described would cause a variable to survive a reboot.

Comment: Environment variables are an OS thing. All processes have them. So if you set an environment variable in one shell and then start a different sort of shell, that variable will be inherited and exist there too. I'm wondering if you may have set som variables in some other startup script like .profile or .login if you're seeing these variables survive reboots.

Comment: I have not edited the .profile and .login so I have no clue why these variables are surviving.

Comment: @Hien: try running `grep LS_COLORS ~/.[a-z]*`. Also, have you tried explicitly unsetting them in your .tcshrc?

Comment: No, I have not. I was under the impression that they would not be permanent as long as I removed the entry from the .tcshrc. I did what you asked and I discovered a setting in my .zshrc that was setting it up. That could have explained it.

Comment: UPDATE: I discovered that the my settings for my PATH was still there. I could have sworn that I had deleted it. Silly me =P. Problem solved thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables set in .tcshrc affect any tcsh shell *that used that version of .tcshrc*.  Modifying the file affects any future tcsh processes you start, but it has no effect on any existing processes.  Once a variable is set in a shell process, the only way to unset it is to use the "unsetenv" command (or "setenv" with a different value).

Any environment variables in your current tcsh process (the one that used the old version of .tcshrc) will also be inherited by any processes you invoke from tcsh.

For example:

1. Start a new tcsh process with `setenv FOO BAR` in your .tcshrc.  $FOO is set to "BAR".
2. Modify your .tcshrc file, deleting the "setenv" command.  *This has no effect on any environment variable in any running process.*
3. Launch bash from your tcsh prompt.  The bash shell process has $FOO set to "BAR", because it inherited it from its parent process (your tcsh process), which got it from the *old* .tcshrc file.
4. Log out and log in again,  All the processes that had $FOO set to "BAR" are now gone.  You have a new tcsh process that read from the *new* .tcshrc, so $FOO isn't set.